# writing file with output function haskell

Tags: file, haskell, io

I would like to write to a file the output of my program automatically, but some errors are appearing. I'm New to haskell.

A really simple example:

```
func =  do
writeFile "file.txt" show(calc)

calc = do return (1+1)
```

I wanted something like this. When I execute the function, creating a file and write on it

The error is:

ERROR "test.hs":5 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')

Thanks.

Comment: For questions regarding errors, please always include the errors in the actual question, complete and unedited. Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Try removing the `do`s from your code, as they are currently unnecessary. Does `func` also take any parameters?

Comment: Just a note that in Haskell whitespace have meaning (like Python), so your tabulation needs to be right in order for your program to be parsed correctly. As a general note, tabulation normally denotes that it's a continuation from the line before.

Comment: @jtcwang Haskell is only whitespace sensitive when you opt-in by eliding "{;}" characters, not always like Python.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. oh right, it wasn't on my mind because no body uses it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors in this code:

- You should remove the `do`s to simplify `func` and `calc`. Technically this is not an error but you should not use unnecessary `do`s because they just clutter up your code.
- `show` has the type `Show a => a -> String`, whereas `calc` has the type `IO String`. Because the types mismatch, your program would not compile.

This is a program with the same functionality which compiles:

```
func :: IO () -- is an IO action
func = writeFile "file.txt" (show calc) -- removed the do

calc :: Integer -- has type integer, meaning "show" is able to operate on it
calc = 1+1 -- removed do and return
```

The reason to remove the return is that `return` does **not** behave like `return` in C-like languages. `return` in Haskell wraps a value in a monadic action whereas in C-like languages it just returns the value of an expression or a variable as result of a function. I would recommend reading [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) chapter for further information as it covers in- and output in Haskell pretty well.

Comment: Technically, `return` wraps a value in a Monadic action, not just `IO`.  It should be noted that `return` is simply a function defined in the base libraries, it is not a keyword in Haskell at all.  It's type is `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`.